# MySQL Amazon Aurora - why is CPU low while max vCPU is high?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora, waits, amazon-rds-aurora

In MySQL Amazon Aurora, is it normal for `CPU` to be be low while other metrics are above the `max vCPU` line?

[image: DB metrics]

Comment: Do you perceive any change in responsiveness?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
What is the Aurora Instance type?
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @RickJames I don't. The only time I do is when I see wait/io/table/sql/handler have a huge spike. Then queries queue up like crazy.

Comment: @mstrom  Please consider posting Additional DB information requested on Mar 6, 2024 for workload analysis to begin.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing surprising about any of this. Your screenshot shows *waits*. There are plenty of reasons for MySQL to be waiting that might have very little to do with CPU. For example, "aurora_respond_to_client" [is about networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/ams-waits.respond-to-client.html).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, I'm curious why max vCPU would be so high, while CPU is so low?

Comment: @mstrom Aurora is notorious for scaling up and down very quickly. The maxes will be due to loads that could be crushed by scaling up for a few moments.